# map example in Effective Haskell (B2.0), Page 58

Tags: haskell

Just so you know, I am somewhat familiar with Haskell but not totally comfortable with it yet so I was going through the book 'Effective Haskell' which is still in early release at PragPub.  I ran into the following.

In the discussion of map on page 58 the author presents the example:

```
map ($ 10) [(+1), (*3), (`div` 5)]
```

which results in `[11, 30, 2]`

This confuses me a lot.  The function application operator (`$`) was introduced back on page 15 as a way of forcing validation of arguments prior to the evaluation of the function.  In that case the `$` comes after the function but before the arguments.

Here we have the `$ 10` *as* the function argument to `map`.  I look at this example and it seems to be completely backward.  I know what is intended but I just cannot make sense of how it works.  In fact, the 'div' piece is a great example of where I go off the rails trying to understand this.  If I execute

```
div 5 $ 10
```

in ghci I get the result `0`.  And, of course, this doesn't work at all:

```
$ 10 `div` 5
```

or even

```
$ 10 div 5
```

So what this really does is

```
div 10 5
```

After playing around in ghci a bit I finally realized that this is equivalent to

```
10 `div` 5
```

So I then tried

```
($ 10) (`div` 5)
```

and also got the right answer.

But what I don't understand is why is the `$` operator needed here?  What does it do?  Why doesn't the following work, instead:

```
map 10 [(`div` 5)]
```

Since that seems it should be equivalent to

```
10 `div` 5
```

But when I try that map expression I get an error that doesn't make any sense to me about a non type-variable argument in the constraint...  So I am at a loss when trying to understand this example.

Answer (score 4):

Ok.  I may have figured this out (but I would like someone to verify I have it right).

`$` is an infix function and `($ 10)` partially applies the right-hand argument to the function.  So it is waiting for the left-hand argument (another function).  In fact, the type of `($ 10)` is

```
Num a => (a -> b) -> b
```

Now the other half of the problem:

```
(`div` 5)
```

is also a partially-applied infix function (by virtue of the back-ticks).  It is waiting on its left-hand argument.  Let's call this `d`.  But the salient fact it that `d` is now a function `Int -> Int`.

So `d` is passed to `($ 10)`.  But the effect is that the `10` is passed to `d` which, by virtue of the partial application, is waiting for the left-hand argument resulting in

```
10 `div` 5
```

Does that sound right?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: Yes, this syntax is called "sections of an infix operator". `($ x)` partially applies the second argument, and is equivalent to `\y -> y $ x`. By contrast, `(x $)` would partially apply the first argument, as in `\y -> x $ y` (GHC actually does something slightly more nuanced here, but let's ignore that). If you want to use an infix operator as a regular "prefix" function, you need to write `($) x y`, or only `($) x` to partially apply it.

Comment: Thanks, everyone.  It sometimes happens that after asking a question it puts that question into perspective so you can answer it.  Glad I got it right.